# Powershell randomly flashes open on Windows 11?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-11

I never use Powershell for anything, I have no need. This is my own personal home machine with Windows 11 Professional.

I had noticed from time to time, maybe once a day or that with no pattern of note, a blue window which looked like powershell would flash up for a split second and disappear. I checked `history` and `Get-History` in Powershell and there is nothing there.

To find the culprit I wrote a small Winforms app in C# which every 10 milliseconds gets the list of open `windows` on the screen using `EnumWindows` Windows API with the full path of the owning executable by calling `QueryFullProcessImageName` with the window handle.

Low and behold today it happens and the window title is Powershell with the path being the full path to windows powershell.

The difference is the path is different when I run it manually using the same command line?

When it showed up in my app, i.e. whatever is executing it randomly, it had a title of `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe` with a path of exactly the same.

When I run it myself first I get the same window title but then another pops in because the window title changed with a title of `Windows Powershell`, the path for both entries when I run it manually is `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_1.18.3181.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\WindowsTerminal.exe`

How the hell do I proceed from here? Is there a way to report on what runs an executable? I don't run Powershell scripts so I don't mind having it locked down if I need to while I find the culrpit.

Comment: You can use AutoRuns to determine which entry in the registry is automatically starting a script Windows Terminal is the default prompt handler on Windows 11.

Comment: Terminal isn't being run automatically, powershell is. It's the other way around than you think. Would the registry open something sporadically? I use my PC for work with a VDI so I sit here all day and it happens about once every two days at random intervals. What is Autoruns?

Comment: Autoruns shows nothing in Everything for powershell

Comment: When you temporarily disable all nonessential processes with AutoRun, from automatically starting, does the behavior still happen?

Comment: It happens once every two days thereabouts, I cannot just not use my PC for 2 days so this approach is not feasible.

Comment: As it currently stands, you have not provided enough information, to diagnose your problem. PowerShell opening could be perfectly normal based on your unique entries in the registry. My comment about Windows Terminal I admit is confusing if you don’t understand what is actually happening, which is difficult to explain in text, unfortunately without more detailed information from your system I cannot help

Comment: If it's a scheduled task, you could in Task Scheduler click "Enable All Tasks History", then search for tasks that happened at that time. See [How to enable Task Scheduler history on Windows 11](https://pureinfotech.com/enable-task-scheduler-history-windows-11/).

Comment: Thank you @harrymc never even thought to check there. Want to suggest an answer? It was a scheduled task for certbot which I did not manually setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem PowerShell job turned out to be a scheduled task for
`certbot` that needed to be disabled.

To track the task, you need to in the Task Scheduler to click
"Enable All Tasks History", then wait for the task to appear.
A task history can be listed in the History pane:

[image]

For more information, see the article
[How to enable Task Scheduler history on Windows 11](https://pureinfotech.com/enable-task-scheduler-history-windows-11/).

Comment: Just for anyone else, I didn't go as far as enabling history, I just right-clicked each scheduled task that didn't look familiar and clicked run and `certbot` gave me the exact same output as the one I was hunting so I deleted it entirely as I don't need it to run on a schedule.